# unable to push file to github

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository. I added a new file to my local repository. Now I want to push the newly added file to my github repository. However, it says

> Everything up-to-date

I used following commands to add file.

```
git add dropDownDate.php
git commit -m "drop down date added"
git push origin master
```

I do not see my dropDownDate.php file in the github url when I refresh the github page. I even tried setting the remote url again by using

```
git remote set-url origin "https://github.com/mygitrepo.git"
```

However, when I again push, it says everything up-to-date.

Please advise me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Run `$ git ls-files`, do you see the file you added?

Comment: @ThomasStringer Yes Thomas. I can see file dateDropDown.php when I run git ls-files

Comment: Try a `git fetch --all` before doing the push.

Comment: Now see what the remote looks like: `$ git ls-tree -r --name-only origin/master`. Does that list it?

Comment: @ThomasStringer No Thomas. remote does not list dateDropDown.php

Comment: @MicroVirus I tried `get fetch --all` and then `git push origin master`. I still get `everything up-to-date` message and the file does not get pushed.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions here?

Comment: Hi All...I was able to solve. I was actually in a branch. Not sure how it was created. I got out of the branch and re committed the file in master and pushed it again. It worked this time. Thanks all for your time and help.